# Typescript mass import template

Tags: typescript, webpack, create-react-app

I use a lot of libraries in my react app. I try to organize code as 1 class=1 file. And thus in the header of each file a have that mass of import statements:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import { style } from 'typestyle';
import { Spring } from 'react-spring';
import { global } from '../../Model/global';
import { action } from 'mobx';
and so on...
```

How can I import it once per project? Or at least use some sort of alias like "import {all of my usual imports} please"

The way it is now is very annoying.

Can you suggest me a solution?

My application is create-react-app React+Typescript 2.0+Webpack solution with VSCode editing tool.

Answer (score 1):

import-and-export them all in a shared imports file that you can then use on top of all your files. Here is an abbreviated example with two imports:

```
// myimports.ts
import * as _React from 'react';
import { observer as _observer } from 'mobx-react';

export React = _React;
export observer = _observer;

// server.ts
import * from './myimports'
```

Comment: >export React = React;
[ts] Cannot assign to 'React' because it is not a variable.

>export let React = React;
[ts] Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'React'.

Comment: Ah sorry @gleb.kudr, typed too fast - please see corrected version

Comment: Partially working, since import * from 'myinports' needs mandatory "as" statement, and you need to use variable declaration on export.